# QVision and undefined reference to `vtable for QVCannyEdgeDetector'

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I have compiled and installed QVision on Archlinux. The libraries I have choosed to be compiled with QVision were qwt,opencv and cgal.
Now I want to compile this code. But can't compile.

```
#include <QVApplication>
#include <QVVideoReaderBlock>
#include <QVImageCanvas>
#include <QVCannyEdgeDetector>
#include <QVDefaultGUI>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
    QVApplication app(argc, argv,
            "Example program for QVision library. Obtains Canny borders from input video frames."
            );

    QVVideoReaderBlock videoReader("Video reader");
    QVCannyEdgeDetector cannyBlock("Canny block");
    QVImageCanvas imageDisplayer("Original image");
    QVImageCanvas edgesDisplayer("Canny edges");

    videoReader.linkProperty(&cannyBlock,"Input image");
    cannyBlock.linkProperty("Input image",imageDisplayer);
    cannyBlock.linkProperty("Output image",edgesDisplayer);

    QVDefaultGUI defaultGUI;

    return app.exec();
}
```

and this is the .pro file I have used for the qt project:

```
LIBS = -L /opt/QVision/lib/lib*
INCLUDEPATH = /opt/QVision/src
TARGET = canvasInteract
SOURCES +=  main.cpp
```

and these are the errors I get:

```
main.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to `QVCannyEdgeDetector::QVCannyEdgeDetector(QString)'
main.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to `vtable for QVCannyEdgeDetector'
main.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to `vtable for QVCannyEdgeDetector'
main.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to `vtable for QVCannyEdgeDetector'
main.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to `vtable for QVCannyEdgeDetector'
main.cpp:-1: error: more undefined reference to `vtable for QVCannyEdgeDetector'
:-1: error: collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: you're not linking a required library

Comment: but this example is provided in the tutorials of its website